# how to schedule mobile phone reminders

Tags: spring, flutter

I have a stateless Flutter app that tracks appointments.  The customer creates multiple events and possible reminders on their Flutter app, which are all stored in the AWS hosted db.

At first thought, the phone (iOS or Android) would create local events.  However, this would fail when users change their phones.  But, if I have the server push the reminder notifications, it would require the app to be on to receive these message (I think) - not to mention the cost of sending all these messages out.

Has anyone solved a problem like this?  I can't seem to think of a good way to approach this.

Comment: How often does a user change their phone anyway? You can just recreate local events when they login on the new phone as needed. As for push notification, the point of GCM and APN is so that the app doesn't have to be on to receive the push message.

Comment: Agreed, its a low risk of changing phones - every two years for most in USA I should think.  I guess making the events on the phone calendars would be a good approach, and upon login it could be an easy check for existing events.

 What are GCM and APN?

Comment: Google Cloud Messaging and Apple Push Notification, basically each OS native service that will always on and listen for incoming notification. Well GCM won't work for the people who choose to not have Google Play, but they're kinda used for notification to be broken anyway since most apps use GCM.